# Would pair production be affected by general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, qft-in-curved-spacetime, pair-production

Given that during pair production a very small amount of energy from the photon becomes gravitational potential energy in the particles, I was curious how this would be affected by general relativity? I was also curious as to whether this would mean that pair production requires higher and higher frequencies of light in proximity to a black hole as the gravitational potential energy becomes larger? My background is a BSc in Chemistry so forgive me for not knowing the specifics of general relativity.

Answer (score 0):

Given that electron-positron pair on top of a hill has more energy than electron-positron pair at sea level, more energy is needed to create the former pair than the latter.

A physicists hiking from sea level lab to a lab at a hill, carrying two photons in his backpack, does the required amount of work on the photons, so that the photons have the same pair production capacity in the lab at the hill as in a lab at the sea level.

Physicist's clock changes so that physicist detects no change in photon's frequency. (Gravitational time-dilation)

If the photons are made to climb by themselves, then their pair production capacity is decreased. Or their energy stays the same, but more energy is needed to produce pairs at that position where the photons are.

In this case physicist's clock changes so that physicist detects a change in photon's frequency.

Perhaps the reader can now figure out the black hole case.